# Does MongoDB Atlas provide offline support?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, react-native

I am creating an App in expo and using nodejs express as backend and mongodb atlas as database.
So I was thinking that if a user is offline and the actions he will perform during offline will automatically sync with online data when he will be offline.

Does this feature mongodb atlas provides ? Or any other option in mongodb provide this feature ?

Comment: See MongoDB Realm, sync, etc.

Comment: So like if am using mongodb atlas and if mongodb realm provides that feature do I need to replace the whole database of mongodb atlas with mongodb realm ?

Comment: You would use Realm on your device which will sync with Atlas. Neither replaces the other one.

Comment: Ok, Got it! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check the paragraph [offline first](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sync/#offline-first) on MongoDB website:

> Realm Sync is built on the assumption that connectivity will drop. We call this mentality offline-first. After you make changes to the local realm on the client device, the Realm SDK automatically sends the changes to the server as soon as possible.

Check also the paragraph [conflict resolution](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sync/#conflict-resolution):

> MongoDB Realm's sync conflict resolution engine is deterministic. Changes received out-of-order eventually converge on the same state across the server and all clients. As such, Realm Sync is strongly eventually consistent.

> In simple terms, Realm Sync's conflict resolution comes down to last write wins. Realm Sync also uses more sophisticated techniques like operational transform to handle, for example, insertions into lists.